# Когда в причастном обороте запятая не нужна?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Действовать в рамках установленных корпоративных нормативов.*

Кажется, здесь запятая не нужна, так как зависимое слово стоит в конце. Правильно ли это?

Answer (score 1):

Слово *установленных* как определение надо отнести к *нормативам*: в данном контексте оно является относительным прилагательным.